# Select element by containing text in TestCafe

Tags: testing, dom, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How can I select an HTML element containing specific text?

In Selenium Xpath selectors are used, but TestCafe doesn't support Xpath.

How do I do it in TestCafe?

Comment: Something like this should work: Selector('a').withText('Exclusions').

Comment: @Janaaaa: how about if you don't know it's `a` tag?

Comment: @pavelsaman: I provided a basic example since the question didn't have additional details.  If the OP could update it with HTML or the div part, then it would be easier to provide an actual solution.

Comment: @Mate Mrše: if you really want xPath, you ca check this github discussion: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1178 there's a workaround, so you can most likely get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/interact-with-the-page.html), in order to select an element containing a certain text, I should use the `.withText()` method with the selected element, example given is:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Example`
    .page `https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;

test('Click test', async t => {
    const selectBasedOnText = Selector('label').withText('I have tried TestCafe');

    await t
        .click(selectBasedOnText);
});
```

for selecting a `label` element with the text "I have tried TestCafe".

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me:

```
import xPathToCss from 'xpath-to-css'
```

and then use as ex:

```
.click(xPathToCss("//a[@class='icon-menu login show-login-panel list-item list-item-next']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

no,
**testcafe supports xpath**

https://github.com/Programmingarea/XpathSelectorIhaveNotCreated

download the xpath selector
after downloading that
go to your testcafe file and type:

importing xpath-selector

`import XPathSelector from './xpath-selector';`

using it:

`const usingxpath = XPathSelector("your xpath");`

simple!
if any doubt ask it in reply

Comment: what is this package './xpath-selector' coz I cant find it?